# Styled Components Transient Props Best Approach

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

To make it easier and more consistent to work on my projects, I decided to create my own component library for React, and to stay with the code itself without having to switch between files (typescript/css), I chose styled-components. At the beginning everything met my expectations, but as is usually the case not for long, of course there had to be some 'feature' that was annoying to me.

I want props given to components to be in the following style:

```
<HyperLink TextWrapping="wrap" Href="www.google.com">Google</HyperLink>
```

For me, this is much more aesthetic and readable than adding '$' before each props.

The problem is that in this form the attributes are added to the DOM, which is an unintended action.

Without going into unnecessary details, how can I deal with it so that I don't have to add $ to each prop or add a "shouldForwardProp" element to each styled element (probably the worst solution due to the multitude of props in the components)

So far I've tried to solve it this way, which of course works, but I don't like the need to convert props for each component and to have separate interface for component and styled component

```
// imported interface from other component, which extends another interface and so on

export interface IStyledTextBlockProps {
  $Type?: TextType;
  $Color?: string;
  $Width?: string;
  $Margin?: string;
  $TextWrapping?: TextWrapping;
  $IsTextSelectionEnabled?: boolean;
}

// text-wrap: ${props => props.$TextWrapping || "nowrap"};
//
// usage in StyledTextBlock


interface IStyledHyperLinkProps extends IStyledTextBlockProps {
  href: string;
}

const StyledHyperLink = styled(StyledTextBlock).attrs<IStyledHyperLinkProps>((props) => ({
  as: "a"
}))<IStyledHyperLinkProps>`
color: ${props => props.$Color || props.theme.colors.accentTextPrimary};
&:hover {
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.accentTextSecondary};
  text-decoration: none;
}
&:active {
  color: ${props => props.theme.colors.accentTextTertiary};
}
`

const addDollarSignPrefix = (obj: Record<string, any>) => {
  const newObj: Record<string, any> = {};
  for (const key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      newObj[`$${key}`] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return newObj;
};

// for example passed TextWrapping prop is in object (...rest) with key TextWrapping and it's working but
// appears in DOM, after 'addDollarSignPrefix', it appears as $TextWrapping in object and works perfectly

interface IHyperLinkProps extends ITextBlockProps {
  Href: string;
}

export const HyperLink: React.FC<IHyperLinkProps> = ({
  Text,
  Href,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const styledProps = addDollarSignPrefix(rest)

  return (
    <StyledHyperLink href={ Href } {...styledProps}>
      { Text || children }
    </StyledHyperLink>
  );
};
```

I think it is possible to solve this in a more clear and simple way (perhaps globally for all components). Unfortunately, nothing comes to mind